# What will be the output of this C++ program?

Tags: c++, c++11, output, c++14

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
   int cin;
   cin >> cin;
   cout << "cin" << cin;
   return 0;
}
```

I saw this question here: http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/c-misc-c-question-8/
The output given by them is: **cin + junk**.

But I am unable to understand how it comes?
Please explain.

Comment: Reading an uninitialized variable has undefined behaviour.

Comment: The program itself has undefined behavior. Which basically means its a code that could *hypothetically* reformat your PC.

Comment: cin is an reserved word in c++ , so you can't use it for a variable name , it will show you an error , the output is nothing because of error

Comment: You should write in this case std::cin >> cin;  and it will work as expected.

Comment: you can use `scanf("%d", &cin);` and then print the value using `printf()` or `cout`. I wonder why you want do that?

Answer (score 5):

The "trick" in this question is

```
cin >> cin;
```

We're so used to seeing `cin >> x` to read `x` from the console that even when `int cin;` is present there is a chance you won't recognise `cin >> cin` as a bit-shift operation.

As has been mentioned, this is UB, which means you can't really *expect* anything. But in the absence of nasal demons, here's what you can *sort of* expect from a modern compiler:

1. The app chooses a register and calls it "cin".
2. It either does not overwrite whatever value that register still has from its last use, or - for a debug build - stores some magic number (chosen by the compiler author) into that register.
3. It then either shifts the value in `cin` right by `cin` bits and throws the answer away (i.e. `cin` is not modified by this operation.) - or the compiler eliminates `cin >> cin` completely because nothing after that line of code is dependant on the subtle side-effects it may have (such as setting the processor's zero flag)
4. The app then writes the string "cin" followed by the value in the register to the console.
5. The app ends cleanly, returning the value 0 to its caller (probably the OS).

**tl;dr;** It prints a random number because `cin >> cin` is a bit-shift operation with no side-effects, not an instruction to read input from the console.

Comment: Incidentally - using a debug build from Visual Studio 2012, the correct answer is "(D) Runtime error". Specifically, MSVS says "Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'cin' is being used without being initialized."

Answer (score 4):

> The output given by them is: cin + junk.

While that is possible, the correct answer is: "I don't know, because the behaviour is undefined."

Let's go over the program line by line:

> ```
> int cin;
> ```

A variable is default initialized. In this case, default initialization means that the value is indeterminate.

> ```
> cin >> cin;
> ```

The bits of variable `cin` are shifted right for `cin` places. However, using an indeterminate value has undefined behaviour.

Rest of the program doesn't matter since behaviour is undefined.

---

In case you were wondering, `std::cin` is not involved because even though it is injected into the global namespace due to `using namespace std`, the local variable `int cin` shadows it.

Comment: *The bits of variable `cin` are shifted right for `cin` places* — well, no. The **value** of `cin` may be shifted, but the result is not stored in `cin`, and the compiler might toss the whole statement since it doesn’t do much of anything. So the real UB is in the output statement.

Comment: @TomZych Whether you store the result of an expression doesn't matter when the behaviour of the program is undefined. I don't disagree that there may be other lines in the program that would cause the behaviour to be undefined if the one I mention was fixed. I stopped reading after encountering the first UB.

Answer (score 0):

Once cin is declared as integer, it can no longer be used for reading in operation.

Again it depends on scope of the cin variable. once the scope is over again cin functions as normal for reading in ops.

even same for cout also.